# Abstraction of functional test code in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I am having difficulty getting my head around functions that return functions that take an argument and apply functions to it that return more functions.
Or something like that. My head hurts.

I have the following code:

```
const app = require('../app'); // an express.js instance
const request = require('supertest');
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); // html parser and jquery selector engine

const html = assertion => response => assertion(cheerio.load(response.text));
const node = selector => html($ => {
  const nodeset = $(selector);
  if (nodeset.length === 0)
    throw new Error('Expected "' + selector + '" to match at least 1 node, but it matched 0.');
});
const anyTextNode = (selector, value) => html($ => {
    const nodeset = $(selector);
    if (nodeset.filter((index, element) => element.children[0].type === 'text' && element.children[0].data === value).length === 0)
        throw new Error('Expected "' + selector + '" to match at least 1 node containing "' + value + '", but found 0.');
});

describe('index route', () => {
  describe('html representation', () => {
    it('should display a search form', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/')
        .expect(node('form>input[type=search][name=q]'))
        .expect(node('form>button[type=submit]'))
        .end(done);
    });
    it('should display a list of links', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/')
        .expect(anyTextNode('body>h2', 'Links'))
        .expect(node('ul>li>a[rel="http..."][href][href!=""]:not(:empty)'))
        .end(done);
    });
```

The first two expectations independently test that there is an input field and a button, and that each are children of a form, but it cannot check that the two elements are children of the *same* form. It would still pass if the DOM was of the form `<form><input/></form></form><button/></form>`.
The second two expectations check that there is a header and a list containing non-empty anchor elements with non-empty hrefs. It does not check that the list immediately follows the header, and if I put in a check for 'h2+ul' there is no way to prove that that is the same UL.

So, I want to add a new function that allows me to build compound tests: first obtain a nodelist from a given selector, then perform other jQuery-ish actions, so in the first example it would take a 'form' selector and then check that it had those two children. In the second example it would test for the existence of a H2 with given text node child, followed by a UL, and that the children of that UL are valid links.

The difficulty comes when I try to abstract the functions like `node` and `anyTextNode` (there are a quite few of them) to reduce duplication. They all call `html()` and pass to that a function that performs the checks. The function that the calls to `html()` return is then passed to the supertest `expect()` call, which invokes it with the response of the server I am testing. I can't see a good design pattern to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an app

```
const app = express();
```

and it has a get method

```
app.get('/', method );
```

the responsibility of the controller should be to call (for example) `template.render` with some data

```
const template = require('../path/to/templateEngine');
const method = (req, res) => {
    const data = { a: 1 };
    res.send(template.render('path/to/desided/template.ext', data));
}
```

it's responsibility is not to return specific markup so in your test you can mock the template (since it's a dependency)

```
const template = require('../path/to/template');
template.render = // some spy jest.fn() or sinon.mock() or chai.spy()

describe('method', () => {
    it('should call the templateEngine.render to render the desired template', () => {
        request(app).get('/');
        // the template might even be an external dependency
        expect(template.render)
            .toBeCalledWith('path/to/desired/template.ext', { a: 1 });
    })
})
```

and then test the template separately;

```
const template = require('../path/to/templateEngine');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

describe('template' => {
  describe('given some mock data', () => {
     const mockData = { /* some mock data */ }
     it('should render the template with mocked data', () => {
        expect(template.render('path/to/desired/template.ext', mockData))
     });
  });
  // and here in the template specification it will be much cleaner 
  // to use cheerio
  describe('form>button', () => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(template.render('path/to/desired/template.ext', mockData));
    it('to have exactly one submit button', () => {
      expect($('form>button[type=submit]')).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

**Edit:**

considering it's a template test you can write it something like this (not tested)

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('supertest');
// template will be Promise<response>
const template = request(app).get('/')

describe('template', () => {
  // if $ is the result from cheerio.load
  // cherrioPromise will be Promise<$>
  // and you can use $.find('selector') to write your assertions
  const cheerioPromise = template.then(response => cheerio.load(response.text()))
  it("should display a search form", () => {
    // you should be able to return promise instead of calling done
    return cheerioPromise.then($ => {
      expect($.find('form>input[type=search][name=q]')).toHaveLength(1);
      expect($.find('form>button[type=submit]')).toHaveLength(1)
    })
  });
  it('should display a list of links', () => {
    return cheerioPromise.then($ => {
      expect($.find('ul>li>a[rel="http..."][href][href!=""]:not(:empty)')) /// some expectation
    });
  });
  it('should have h2 with text "Links"', () => {
    return cheerioPromise.then($ => {
      expect($.find('body.h2').text()).toEqual('Links');
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for zooming out and spotting a higher level problem. I was aware that I haven't bothered setting up a mocking system yet, as I am dependant on data in a local elasticsearch instance at the moment, but I had not thought of testing the template with mock data (since the template itself is 'static'). I also seem to have fallen for the fallacy of writing integration tests when I have been intending to write unit tests. For the purposes of answering the original question though, could you consider these tests to be testing the output of the template, parsed into a DOM.

Comment: @NicholasShanks hopefully my edit shows how can you define your expectations without any functions

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it solves all of your problems, but it might help find the right track:

By making `node` accept both its search context and a query, *and* return its result, it can be chained. This makes your error messages easier to work with, and you can split up your queries. E.g.:

```
const node = (parent, query) => {
  const child = parent.querySelector(query);

  if (!child) 
    throw `Node "${query}" does not exist in ${parent}`;

  return child;
}

node(node(document, "form"), "input"); // Instead of `node("form input")`
```

This calls the query for `<form>` first, and throws if there isn't any (logging that the actual "form" element is missing, giving you an idea where to look for). Only *after* the `<form>` has been found, the form is searched for an input.

The use-case for looking for multiple elements can be added by creating a `nodes` function:

```
const nodes = (parent, queries) => queries
    .map(q => node(parent, q));
```

### Example

In the example below I've made three documents. Our test wants to assert that:

- There's a form
- The form has all of these:

  - A text input
  - A password input
  - A submit input

The first two divs contain faulty HTML. The last one passes the test.

```js
const node = (parent, query) => {
  const child = parent.querySelector(query);
  
  if (!child) 
    throw `Node "${query}" does not exist in ${parent.id || parent}`;
    
  return child;
}

const nodes = (parent, queries) => {
  return queries
    .map(q => node(parent, q));
};



// Test containers:
[ "twoForms", "noForm", "correctForm" ]
  .map(id => document.getElementById(id))
  .forEach(parent => {
    try {
      nodes(
        node(parent, "form"),
        [
          "input[type=text]",
          "input[type=password]",
          "input[type=submit]"
        ]
      );
      console.log(`Wrapper ${parent.id} has a correct form`);
    } catch(err) { console.log(err); }
  });
```

```css
div[id] { padding: .5em; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="twoForms">
  Two forms:
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password">
  </form>
  <form>
    <input type="submit" value="sign in">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="noForm">
  No forms:
  <input type="text" placeholder="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" value="sign in">
</div>

<div id="correctForm">
  Passing form:
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="sign in">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is more along the lines that I had been thinking, some kind of nested (check, [subchecks]) tree, which I was still trying to work out, but as pointed out in the other answer, I should have been testing the template independently with mock inputs, not checking it's contents in the controller tests, so I'm going to do that.